# Determining order of function calls in PHP

Tags: php

I'm writing a class - called `MenuBuilder` - in PHP 7 which is intended to build navigation menus in a web application.

The way in which the class works is by building up an output buffer which holds the markup for the menus.

It starts off by declaring an empty variable inside `class MenuBuilder`:

```
private $output_buffer = '';
```

There is a method to add to it:

```
protected function add_to_output_buffer($input = '') {
    if ($input !== '') {
        $this->output_buffer .= $input;
    }
}
```

And a method to display the menu markup:

```
public function render() {
    echo $this->output_buffer;
}
```

So far quite straightforward. Here's the problem... When I add a link to the menu I use this method:

```
public function add_menu_item($item) {
    $this->menu_items[] = $item;
}
```

This builds up an array (`$this->menu_items`) and there is then another method which cycles through the items in it to add them to the output buffer. It's quite long but a shortened version of it is here:

```
public function create_links() {
       foreach ($this->menu_items as $item) {
           $output = '';
           $output = '<a href="'.$item['link'].'">'.$item['text'].'</a>';
           $this->add_to_output_buffer($output);
       }
}
```

There is quite a lot of logic in `create_links()` because various classes and other things get applied to the links, but essentially it has to work like this because it needs to loop through the full array of links.

**The problem:**
If I want to add random HTML at any point in the menu, I have a function to do this:

```
public function add_misc_html($html = '') {
    $this->output_buffer .= $html;
}
```

But in my script which uses these functions, it doesn't know the order in which things are being called. An example:

```
$MenuBuilder = new MenuBuilder;
$MenuBuilder->add_menu_item(['text' => 'Link 1', 'link' => '#']);
$MenuBuilder->add_menu_item(['text' => 'Link 2', 'link' => '#']);
$MenuBuilder->add_misc_html('<h1>testing add_misc_html</h1>');
$MenuBuilder->add_menu_item(['text' => 'Link 3', 'link' => '#']);
$MenuBuilder->create_links();
$MenuBuilder->render();
```

So the problem is that the desired output is:

```
<a href="#">Link 1</a>
<a href="#">Link 2</a>
<h1>testing add_misc_html</h1>
<a href="#">Link 3</a>
```

But this won't work, because when I call `create_links()` it's not aware of `add_misc_html` and where this is called in the overall structure of the calls to `MenuBuilder`

What ways can I achieve the desired output? Please note that `add_misc_html()` needs to work anywhere it gets called, prior to `render()`. There is a whole load of other stuff in the class to open the menu and close it, so it needs to be able to modify the `$this->output_buffer` at any point.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't add it right away instead of waiting for the `create_links` call? Otherwise you could add an order, but then you should add a mapping, something like `array( 0 => array( type => misc, key => 1), 1 => array( type => menu, key => 4))`

Comment: @giorgio Yes, very much so. Consider an example where there are 100 links. If I wanted to use add_misc_html() at, say 15 *different* points, to output markup *in between* those links - the order matters.

Comment: lol :p no I mean, why don't you add the menu items to the output buffer immediately when the `add_link` function is being called, the same applies to the `misc_html`. As when looking at your code, I don't see anything that has to wait until all menu items are known.

Comment: @giorgio All of the menu links do need to be known. The code I've posted here for create_links() is massively simplified to what's actually there because it does all sorts of other things inside the foreach() which requires every item to be present before it can build the output buffer up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your `add_misc_html` writes directly to your output buffer, where `add_menu_item` modifies the structure of your object, you can't mix these calls. You must first write your modified object state to the buffer and only then write "misc" HTML to the buffer. This is pretty bad though.

There are many solutions you can come up with but the one I will suggest to you is to not have an output buffer at all, and possibly extend the logic of the class with a couple other classes.

```
class MenuBuilder {

    protected $items = [];

    public function add(MenuItem $item) {
        $this->items[] = $item;
    }

    public function render() {
        return join('', $this->items);
    } 
}
```

Where you will have different types of menu items, like `Link` and `Misc` that are used in your example.

```
interface MenuItem {
    public function __toString();
}

class LinkMenuItem implements MenuItem {

    protected $link;
    protected $text;

    public function __construct($link, $text) {
        $this->link = $link;
        $this->text = $text;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return '<a href="' . $this->link . '">'. $this->text .'</a>';
    }
}

class MiscMenuItem implements MenuItem {

    protected $html;

    public function __construct($html) {
        $this->html = $html;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return $this->html;
    }
}
```

And now your class will be used like this.

```
$builder = new MenuBuilder();
$builder->add(new LinkMenuItem('#', 'Link 1'));
$builder->add(new LinkMenuItem('#', 'Link 2'));
$builder->add(new MiscMenuItem('<h1>Testing html</h1>');
$builder->add(new LinkMenuItem('#', 'Link 3'));
```

And when you want to render.

```
$builder->render();
```

### Edit

Based on the discussion in the comments I am coming to think that you are having trouble rendering the objects as HTML hierarchically. Again there are a number of ways you can go about this, I am just proposing one

You can add a base class that your other menu items will extend

```
abstract class ParentMenuItem extends MenuItem {

    protected $children = [];

    public function addChild(MenuItem $child) {
        $this->children[] = $child;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return '<ul>' . join(null, $this->children) . '</ul>';
    }

}
```

Then your `LinkMenuItem` will look like this

```
class LinkMenuItem extends ParentMenuItem {

    protected $link;
    protected $text;

    public function __construct($link, $text) {
        $this->link = $link;
        $this->text = $text;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return '<a href="' . $this->link . '">'. $this->text .'</a>' . parent::__toString();
    }
}
```

When you want to add children you will add them to the menu item they belong to (duh?)

```
$builder = new MenuBuilder();

$link1 = new LinkMenuItem('#', 'Link 1');
$link1->addChild(new LinkMenuItem('#', 'Child1'));
$link1->addChild(new LinkMenuItem('#', 'Child2'));
$builder->add($link1);

$builder->add(new LinkMenuItem('#', 'Link 2'));
$builder->add(new MiscMenuItem('<h1>Testing html</h1>'));
$builder->add(new LinkMenuItem('#', 'Link 3'));
```

You can also enable chaining to avoid using variables and all kinds of other good stuff like factories etc.

Comment: `LinkMenuItem` and `MiscMenuItem` should implement the `MenuItem` interface.

Comment: @king_nak whoops.

Comment: @php_nub_qq The code you've provided works. The bit I'm struggling to understand is where my create_links() logic would happen though? This does all kinds of processing with the full array of links it receives (it has to have the full array to work). Please note that in my original post the create_links() function has been simplified. It has to loop through the full array and will ultimately add markup to things such as <a> or <li> elements. I guess it should be in LinkMenuItem::_toString() ?

Comment: @Andy it depends on your logic, where are these modifications coming from? You can extend the menu item objects to have functions such as `addClass` and whatever you need and the code that is issuing the item to the `MenuBuilder` can issue it with the necessary modifications?

Comment: @php_nub_qq in the original code it needed the full array of links because each one had a "level" (1, 2 or 3) to say how "deep" it was in a hierarchy. This was used to open and close certain <ul> elements, and add various classes. It looped through the full array to do this. But I've managed to adapt it to work where it can accept single inputs using $builder->add() and then use class variables to work out where it's up to. Thanks for your help though, the solution you posted was very helpful.

Comment: @Andy the method you are referring to has been used a lot in php but is obsolete imho and unfortunately it is still being used. The levels you are referring to are what is called derived data - it depends on other data and can be recalculated. What if your menu items switch order, you will need to go and update these levels - that's wrong. Using proper OOP you can construct valid HTML without the need of such "broken by design" algorithms.

Comment: @Andy I have added another example to the answer that I think may help you get a better understanding.